# Check server connectivity

Tags: android, connection, urlconnection

I need to test server connectivity whether it is down or up. I am using the code below but it always shows the error "--checkServerConnected NO--" even if I put in the correct url.

```
public void checkServerConnected() {
    try{
        URL myUrl = new URL("http://www.google.co.uk");
        URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
        connection.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("--","--checkServerConnected NO-- ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Put code e.printStackTrace(); before your Log.e and show the track trace pls.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added Internet permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If you uses Internet permission,then change your method like this.Because server related actions didnot do on main Thread.so put it on a thread.

```
public void checkServerConnected() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try{
                    URL myUrl = new URL("http://www.google.co.uk");
                    URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
                    connection.connect();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("--","--checkServerConnected NO-- ");
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to server", 1000).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();

    }
```

Comment: Yes. I am able to connect the internet. The url is correct but not sure why it return invalid.

Comment: The class(Activity) where you are using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are invoking this method in your main thread? The  web operation can not be in the main thread since Android OS4.0,make sure that this method is called in a sub-thread.

Answer (score 0):

use HttpURLConnection in place URLConnection . with which you can easily get Response code for different condition. when Response code 200 then your server is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added the permission in your manifest file

Also, you cannot perform networking operations on the main thread. So either put this code in a new thread or call the function from a thread.

If it still doesn't work then try using classes from Apache's HTTP library

```
try {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    Log.e("Server Response", response.getStatusLine().toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Not working. I calling from onCreate method means it is the main thread?

Comment: put this in a new thread which you run from the OnCreate method